# Intellij Project View does not show log files

Tags: intellij-idea

Somehow IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 does not show *.log files as you can see in the picture. I tried to delete .idea folder and uninstall .ignore plugin but didn't help.

How to see *.log files in Project View in Intellij ?

[image]

Comment: Please check that you don't have .log extension ignored in File | Settings | Editor | File Types, [Ignore files and folders](https://i.imgur.com/gwoSwTT.png).

Comment: Yes i already checked that, there is no .log extension.

Comment: What's the size of the log file? Are the any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Do you use any third-party plug-ins to handle the log files? What's the file type mapping for the .log extension?

Comment: Log file size is 30KB. I use [Ansi Highligter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9707-ansi-highlighter), uninstall and restart ide does not change anything. I checked idea.log, there is nothing about news-collector.log. For the last question, i check Settings | Editor | File Types, Android Logcat has *.log pattern.

Comment: Try mapping it to the text files instead: https://i.imgur.com/BwUZFXJ.png.

Comment: Just removing *.log from Android Logcat works.  Should i still mapping it to the text files ?

Comment: It should be the default mapping so that you can open the logs in the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the file type mapping is correct and `*.log` extension is associated with the **Text** file type in File | Settings | Editor | File Types:

[image: Text]

Comment: Modern IDEA uses "**TextMate Bundle**" plugin for text files and `.log` is supported format: the plugin provides regex highlighting for severity/stack traces etc. Sometimes regexes are sluggish, especially on **large** files.